# Sphinx SE Fetching Records issue?

Tags: sphinx

In SphinSE, i can fetch any records from sphinx server.

Example : I having following records:

Id  Name      Item   Price

1   bike      1000     1000

2   Car       200      200

To Fetching records, i have used following query

select * from indexname WHERE query='1000;mode=any';

It has return 2 records. How can i get record, which record having Item AS 1000.

select * from indexname WHERE query='@Item 1000;mode=extended';

It has return empty set. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from indexname WHERE query='@Item 1000;mode=extended';
```

Taht should work, if Item is a field (ie you havent defined it as an attribute)

If an attribute something like

```
 select * from indexname WHERE query=';filter=Item,1000';
```

should do it.